# retrieve the latest timestamp value from the oracle table

Tags: oracle

I need the get the latest timestamp from a table. The timestamp values ore in oracle format.I have tried the following but not giving me the latest row that has the most recent timestamp:

```
SELECT max(to_char(CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(GET_UTC_TIMESTAMP(T."Timestamp", TMZDIFF) AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern') AS DATE),'dd-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi')) as DATETIME FROM DW.KPX_PHYSICAL_MEMORY_DV T where T."Node" like 'server%'
```

I need to have the most recent Timestamp value from the table called KPX_PHYSICAL_MEMORY_DV . Any idea how I would do this easily?

Comment: You probably need to order the records first.

Comment: @Daffi, no I tried order by too. It is still not giving me the latest records timestamp.

Answer (score 3):

Do not cast it to char or do cast it to `YYYYMMDD` rather than `dd-Mon-yyyy` as you do.

```
SELECT max(CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(GET_UTC_TIMESTAMP(T."Timestamp", TMZDIFF) AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern') AS DATE) as DATETIME 
FROM DW.KPX_PHYSICAL_MEMORY_DV T 
where T."Node" like 'server%'
```