# How can I convert this SQL to Oracle format

Tags: oracle

I need to issue a select statment to an oracle table as below:

```
SELECT 
    T."Node" 
FROM 
    DW.KPX_PHYSICAL_MEMORY_DV T 
where 
    T."Node" like 'cigp%' 
    AND  CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(GET_UTC_TIMESTAMP(T."Timestamp", TMZDIFF) AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern') as DATETIME)>='04-Jun-13 10.46.46.00'
```

I get invalid data type, I am very new to oracle. Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Timestamp is type char and the values are like this:

```
1121004234558000
1121004234523000
1121004234550000
1121004234513000
1121004234559000
```

I need to convert the time stamp to human readable format and and select based on greater than a value.

I tried this sql query but does not seem like it is working, I get "invalid relational operator" error.

```
SELECT T."Node" as LPAR, CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(GET_UTC_TIMESTAMP(T."Timestamp", TMZDIFF) AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern') AS DATE) as TimeStamp,T."MAX_Memory_Size_MB",T."MIN_Comp_Memory",T."AVG_Comp_Memory", T."MAX_Comp_Memory", T."MIN_Non_Comp_Memory", T."AVG_Non_Comp_Memory", T."MAX_Non_Comp_Memory" FROM DW.KPX_PHYSICAL_MEMORY_HV T where T."Node" like 'server%'

and 

CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(GET_UTC_TIMESTAMP(T."Timestamp", TMZDIFF) AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern') AS DATE) as TimeStamp > '04-Jun-2013 02:00:00 PM'
```

Comment: You didn't mention what you've tried already.

Comment: `DATETIME` isn't an Oralce data type for a start... Is `GET_UTC_TIMEZONE` a user-defined function, or are you just copying syntax from another RDBMS. The Oracle [SQL Langueage Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/toc.htm) might be a good place to start.

Comment: This appears to be a followup to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16925410/2091410). Could you post your `KPX_PHYSICAL_MEMORY_DV` table structure with the question? It's hard to know if all those function calls are really necessary, so if some of them can be gotten out of the way the question (and answer) may become clearer.

Comment: @Ed Gibbs, I modified the orinal post.

Comment: Thanks! What format are the timezone values in? I tried finding date parts there and no luck. Similarly, they're way too big to be UNIX Timestamp values. What are they?

Comment: @ed gibbs, when I do this: to_char(CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(GET_UTC_TIMESTAMP(T."Timestamp", TMZDIFF) AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern') AS DATE),'dd-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi') as DATETIME, I get this: 04-Jun-2013 02:45

Comment: Where does `GET_UTC_TIMESTAMP` come from? It's not an Oracle function.

Comment: @Ed Gibbs, I am not sure it is part of oracle or not but, it was givend to be by a dba.